# Click event in electron not working AND mouse icon not changing when I hover over a html button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron, addeventlistener

I'm working on a project using the electron framework. I have an HTML file, a CSS file, and a Javascript file. The problem I'm having is that when I hover over a button, the hand pointer icon doesn't pop up even though I have given it the attribute to do so in my CSS code.

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<button style="background: url(images/cross.svg);" alt="exit" id="exit_button"></button>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```css
#exit_button{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 15px;
    border: 0px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

And here is my Javascript code:

```js
//variables
const remote = require('electron').remote;

const exit_button = document.getElementById("exit_button");

//Firing functions
exit_button.addEventListener('click', close_window);

//functions
function close_window() {
    console.log("exit_button clicked, window closing..."); //This DOESN'T print
    var current_window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    current_window.close();
};
```

The click event assigned to the `exit_button` isn't working either along with the pointer issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the problem was that I had

```css
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-app-region: drag;
```

In its parent. This stopped me from clicking it.
I had to add the following in my css:

```css
-webkit-user-select: auto;
-webkit-app-region: no-drag;
```

And now my css looks like this:

```css
#exit_button{
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0px;
    width: 15px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 7.5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    -webkit-user-select: auto;
    -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried putting your code in a JSFiddle and it worked without issue. Maybe there's something else that's conflicting? Use developer tools and disable styles one by one to find the culprit.

Comment: I have found out the CSS was causing the problems, however now there's a new problem, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, I've found out what the problem was!